# PHP: Convert string back to normal

Tags: php, regex, string, hex

I found a function in MediaWiki Source, which converts a string with umlauts to HEX format.

Now i want to convert the formated string back to the string with umlauts.

The function:

```
    $Umlaut = "löschen";

    $out = preg_replace_callback("/([\\xc0-\\xff][\\x80-\\xbf]*)/",'stripForSearchCallback', $Umlaut);

    function stripForSearchCallback( $matches ) {
         return 'u8' .  bin2hex( $matches[1] );
    }

    echo $out;
```

Output: "lu8c3b6schen"

Now i want to convert "lu8c3b6schen" back to "löschen".

How can i do this please?

Comment: Match for hexnum tuples and use `chr(hexdec())` as callback.

Comment: Is your output even valid? I though that hex format should be a pair of `[a-z0-9]`, but you have an uneven format `8c3b6`. Maybe I'm missing something ? Also notice that a regex would most likely mess your sentence for example if you have numbers in it `löschen 65` or consecutive hex letters: **acce** nt

Comment: Yes you are right. I dont think its HEX. Mediawiki says the following:  "Armor a case-folded UTF-8 string to get through MySQL's
  * fulltext search without being mucked up by funny charset
  * settings or anything else of the sort." - But i cant find any function which is able to convert it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
$string = "lu8c3b6schen";

$out = preg_replace_callback("/u8([a-f0-9]{4})/",'unstrip', $string);

function unstrip( $matches ) {
    $decoded = hex2bin( $matches[1] );
    return $decoded ? $decoded : $matches[1];
}

echo $out;
```

Comment: *sigh* How did I not see the `u`, +1